# Ruby development environment (OS X vs. Ubuntu)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2

I'm a developer who uses RoR-CoffeeScript-Sass-Passenger-Apache. We use EC2 for our deployment and we have Macbook Airs for development. While the rails community is very much Mac-friendly, because of the whole deployment stack difference in dev vs. prod, I'm using a virtualbox+ubuntu while my peers are developing on OS X native.

Having on OS X Native adds more problem as we have more dependencies in the stack (Solr, Beanstalk, Mongodb and more which works well in Ubuntu)

I'm looking for suggestions on how Rails developers using Mac and Amazon EC2 can have their dev and prod environment setup.

Would also like feedback on use of vagrant for distribution of development environments for this use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our team has been been developing on Macs and deploying to Ubuntu on EC2 for three years now with very few issues. Several things have helped make this a smooth process:

1. We can run the entire app stack** on a Mac. Between macports, homebrew, and building from source when necessary, we have managed to get every piece of technology that we run in prod working on our dev boxes. The way the pieces are configured and fit together is different locally (in prod, for example, we auto-discover our memcached instance, whereas locally it's hard coded) but every integration can be tested on Macs first before going to prod.
2. Our continuous build system is on the same setup as our prod boxes. This means if you check in some code that depends on some piece of local magic it's discovered quickly.
3. We run a soak (some people call this staging or integ) stack that is configured identically to production. This sometimes causes some development overhead but has so many benefits that it's well worth it. All code goes through this stack before being pushed to prod.

This setup has worked well enough that over time we've allowed more parts of the setup to drift apart. We used to run passenger locally (like we do in prod) but now use Pow. We regularly experiment with new ruby versions in development for some time before upgrading the rest of the stack.

I've had to develop using a virtualized environment for other projects (OSX + CentOS in VirtualBox) and definitely found it more painful that all-native. For one, it felt like managing two machines instead of one. Everything also felt sloooooowww.

If there's a piece of the stack that is painful to run on the Mac, I would definitely prefer to take the hit of either a) spending the time of getting it working locally or b) abstracting that piece away, rather than pay the tax of dealing with a virtual environment.

** I'm only including the Rails app and direct dependencies in this discussion. For example, we use puppet to configure our EC2 fleet, but don't run it on our dev boxes.

Answer (score 3):

A common practice would be to replicate your stack as a "staging" environment. With EC2, you can just create AMI's of your existing machines and duplicate them, turning them on only to  test deploys, and run your tests to make sure everything is running properly before deploying it to production. Or often you may wish to leave it on permanently so developers can quickly deploy updates or patches to test as need be.

Doing it this way ensures that you have an exact replica of your production system to test before rolling out, thereby eliminating any (catastrophic) issues pertaining to the deploy sneaking out into production.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. That does answer part of my question. By your answer, I assume you suggest me to use OS X as default development environment and push to "prod" replicas for test-deploys. Also, how do you setup your local environment when you have a dependency stack?

Comment: To add, I am looking for a answer for using Native OS X vs. Virtualbox with pros & cons when the dependency stack becomes big.

Comment: On development machines, it should be as simple as setting up the stack as needed on OSX. You can create a script that does everything for new developers to make it less painful. Expecting every developer to run in Virtual box, seems highly counter-productive. If you are not a distributed work force, a simple answer is to buy or re-purpose a computer for nix, and allow each developer their own port to run their code and test on.

Comment: I guess to further that, if you are distributed, you could just set up a development environment in EC2, and allow each developer their own port, and DB, etc. so that they can develop/push their code to their own home dirs there.

Comment: Writing a script to setup stack on OSX is a good option. We are based out of India (slow-speeds) and hence writing code on EC2 is difficult :)